# Simple netty echo server not allowing multiple clients to connect simultaneously

Tags: java, netty

EDIT: I removed the client code because the problem appears to be on the server.

I implemented a very simple netty echo server similar to what is suggested in a tutorial.

The problem is that when I attempt to run multiple clients pointing to the same server, it seems the server only allows one connection at a time. For example, when I run "telnet localhost 8080" and try to use the echo server from two different clients, the first one succeeds while the second one fails (doesn't reply back). Also, when I start multiple netty clients, I see on the server side that messages are only being received from one client port -- when that client finishes and closes its connection, the second client proceeds. Does anyone know why this might be happening? This is using netty 3.5.1. Also worth noting, netstat is running very slowly on my machine even though there isn't a lot of output. Here's my source code for the server (problem seems to be on the server since I can reproduce the problem with telnet):

Server:

```
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
import org.jboss.netty.bootstrap.ServerBootstrap;
import org.jboss.netty.channel.Channel;
import org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelFactory;
import org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext;
import org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelPipeline;
import org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelPipelineFactory;
import org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels;
import org.jboss.netty.channel.ExceptionEvent;
import org.jboss.netty.channel.MessageEvent;
import org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelHandler;
import org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannelFactory;

public class Server {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ChannelFactory factory =
                new NioServerSocketChannelFactory(
                        Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(),
                        Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor());

        ServerBootstrap bootstrap = new ServerBootstrap(factory);

        bootstrap.setPipelineFactory(new ChannelPipelineFactory() {
            public ChannelPipeline getPipeline() {
                return Channels.pipeline(new EchoServerHandler());
            }
        });

        bootstrap.setOption("child.tcpNoDelay", true);
        bootstrap.setOption("child.keepAlive", true);
        bootstrap.bind(new InetSocketAddress(8080));
    }

    private static AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(0);

    public static class EchoServerHandler extends SimpleChannelHandler {

        @Override
        public void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, MessageEvent e) {
            Channel ch = e.getChannel();
            int t = count.incrementAndGet();
            if (t % 1000 == 0) {
                System.out.println("server " + t + " " + e.getChannel());
            }
            ch.write(e.getMessage());
        }

        @Override
        public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ExceptionEvent e) {
            e.getCause().printStackTrace();
            Channel ch = e.getChannel();
            ch.close();
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE: It appears that I can only run as many clients as I have worker threads on the server (from some experimentation with different numbers of clients and different fixed worker thread pool sizes). Here is a jstack from one of the worker threads, stuck on epollWait (anyone know why?):

```
"New I/O  worker #1" prio=10 tid=0x00007fdba801a000 nid=0x2b84 runnable [0x00007fdc296c2000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.poll(EPollArrayWrapper.java:228)
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(EPollSelectorImpl.java:81)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:87)
    - locked <0x00000006b11732b0> (a sun.nio.ch.Util$2)
    - locked <0x00000006b11732a0> (a java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet)
    - locked <0x00000006b1173080> (a sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:98)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.SelectorUtil.select(SelectorUtil.java:52)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:209)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:35)
    at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:102)
    at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Comment: Figured it out. I need to set the number of worker threads to be no more than the number of threads the executor can produce (3rd argument to the constructors of ChannelFactory objects).

Comment: If you find the solution, can you add an answer to your question?